# Do concepts like Map and Reduce apply to all Functional Programming Languages?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have just started delving into the world of functional programming.

A lot of OOP (Object Oriented Programming) concepts such as inheritance and polymorphism apply to most modern OO languages like C#, Java and VB.NET.

But how about concepts such as Map, Reduce, Tuples and Sets, do they apply to all FP (Functional Programming) languages?

I have just started with F#.  But do aforementioned concepts apply to other FP like Haskell, Nemerle, Lisp, etc.?

Comment: Polymorphism is not an OO concept. It is a general concept with a lot of different "implementations". What you probably refer to is "subtype polymorphism". Functional languages for example uses "Parametric Polymorphism" or "Ad-hoc polymorphism",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You bet.  The desirable thing about function programming is that the mathematical concepts you describe are more naturally expressed in an FP.

It's a bit of tough going, but John Backus' [Turing Award paper](http://www.thocp.net/biographies/papers/backus_turingaward_lecture.pdf) in which he described functional (or "applicative") programming is a good read.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is good too.

Comment: @Charlie: That paper looks a bit tough to swallow for me in my current condition.  But looks like something I can spend some time on to actually learn.  Thanks.

Comment: "That which does not kill me makes me stronger." ;-)

Comment: @Charlie: I thought that applied only to spicy food.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes; higher-order functions, algebraic data types, folds/catamorphisms, etc are common to almost all functional languages (though they sometimes go by slightly different names in each language).

Answer (score 2):

Functional tools apply to all programming, not just languages that handle that explicitly.  For example, python has `map` and `reduce` builtin functions that do exactly what you expect, besides out of order evaluation.  you'll need something like the multiprocessing module to get really clever.

Even if the language doesn't provide the exact primitives, most modern languages still make it possible to get the desired effect with a bit more work.  This is similar to the way a class-like concept can be coded in pure C.

Comment: +1 "most modern languages still make it possible to get the desired effect with a bit more work" <-- With C# I can implement Map & Reduce but the code gets quite hairy...

Comment: it'd be possible with any Turing complete language (pretty much everything but the C preprocessor, including Ook and Brainfuck), no?

Comment: Obviously there is not computational power inferred by functional programming that a turing trap couldn't achieve.  The real benefit is the expressive power of the language combined with the feature of efficient implementation of the operators.  It is very difficult to get a turing trap language to both perform the action in a way that is efficient and also easy to understand.

Comment: @Carson A Turing trap (IIRC) can perform the result of the map-reduce abstraction, but only a deity could make map-reduce work *semantically* in terms of a Turing trap.

Comment: RE "With C# I can implement Map & Reduce but the code gets quite hairy..." LINQ is FP embedded nicely in C# for all IEnumerables. Map is just Select, Reduce is Agregate, Filter is Where, ...

Answer (score 2):

I would interpret what you're asking as, "Are higher-order functions (map, reduce, filter, ...) and immutable data structures (tuples, cons lists, records, maps, sets, ...) common across FP languages?" and I would say, absolutely yes.

Like you say, OOP has well known pillars (encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism). The "pillars" of functional programming I'd say are 1) Using functions as first-class values and 2) Expressing yourself without side effects.

You'll likely find common tools to apply these ideas across various FP languages (F# is an excellent choice BTW!) and you'll see them finding their way into more mainstream languages; maybe in a less recognizable form (e.g. LINQ's Select = map, Aggregate = reduce/fold, Where = filter, C# has light weight lambda syntax, System.Tuple, etc.).

As an aside, the thing that seems to be generally missing from non-explicitly-FP languages is good immutable data structures and syntax support for them (not merely a library) which makes it hard to stick to pillar #2 in those languages. F# lists, records, tuples, etc. all are good examples of great language and library combined support for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to jump into the deep end and understand why these concepts are not just conventional but, ahem, *foundational*, check out the paper ["Functional programming with bananas, lenses, envelopes and barbed wire"](http://www.springerlink.com/content/77t3588175m4h5n7/).

Answer (score 0):

They apply to all languages that contain data types that can be "mapped" and "reduced", i.e maps, arrays/vectors, or lists.

In a "pure lambda calculus" language, where every data structure is defined via function application, you can of course apply functions in parallel (i.e., in a call fn(expr1, expr2), you can evaluate expr1 and expr2 in parallel), but that isn't really what map/reduce is about.